# How do I specify an array of objects in Typescript using interface with specific attribute naming

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript thought I got a hang of it but ran into an issue today of creating an interface for a complex dynamic object from JSON, converted it to generic names for the attributes below.

I'm getting error messages "Source has X element(s) but target allows only 1.". How can I extend my arrays to accept multiple objects, but still retain the attribute names? I have seen indexer solutions but it seems to loose the value of getting an expected JSON object overview.

```
interface Props {
arrayName: [
    {
      attributeName: string;
      attributeArray: [
        {
          attributeToken: string;
          attributeArray: [
            {
              attributeName: number;
              attributeName: number;
              comment: string;
            },
          ];
        },
      ];
      attributeArray: [
        {
          attrbuteName: string;
          attributeValue?: number;
          attributeLevel: number | null;
          attributeMeasurement: number | null;
          attributeUnit?: string;
        },
      ];
      attributeBoolean: false;
      attributeValue: 199.0;
    }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `[SomeType]` is a tuple with one element. To declare an array with an unknown number of items use `SomeType[]`

The tuple form lets you make a type like `[number, string, boolean]` which requires a number at index zero, a string at index 1, and a boolean at index 2. There must be exactly 3 items in the array, and the type of each index is known at compile time.

So you don't want a tuple here. Fixing it is simple. Instead of:

```
      attributeArray: [
        {
          attributeName: number;
          attributeName: number;
          comment: string;
        },
      ];
```

You want:

```
      attributeArray: {
        attributeName: number;
        attributeName: number;
        comment: string;
      }[],
```